# Mathjax rendering issues with Bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm attempting to host a draft of a book (gitbook) from my gh-pages website, but am having issues getting mathjax equations to render.

**When loading mathjax via CDN:**

The book renders mathjax locally and also from a remote server in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. However if I serve the code from the /docs folder on github, Chrome and Firefox do not render the mathjax, but Safari does. From what I can see mathjax loads from the CDN, but the fonts don't load on Chrome and Firefox - I assume this has to do with the way GH-pages serves content.

An example of this issue (code) can be seen at this repo:
https://github.com/ctufts/gh-pages-mathjax-rendering/tree/master 
and is rendered at this site:
https://miningthedetails.com/gh-pages-mathjax-rendering/

**Static copy of Mathjax:**

As a work around I then tried to use a local library of mathjax, but this doesn't seem to work with bookdown. The configurations are shown below:

```
---
title: "A Book"
author: "Frida Gomam"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    mathjax: local
    self_contained: false
  bookdown::pdf_book: default
---
```

For the same example above, the complete code can be seen here:
https://github.com/ctufts/gh-pages-mathjax-rendering/tree/local_mathjax

Pandoc states that it cannot find the local files when rendering the gitbook:

*pandoc: libs/mathjax-local/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1*

but I have verified that they are at the designated path in the output directory as specified in the [html_document docs](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html)

Comment: This is odd. MathJax works for this example project: https://rstub.github.io/bookdown-chapterbib/.

Answer (score 1):

An old post, but I've encountered exactly the same problem today. The problem was in a Firefox extension that was blocking `mathjax.rstudio.com` considering it as a tracker.

Comment: How did you get Firefox to unblock `mathjax.rstudio.com`?

Comment: I've switched off this particular extension. But it was a long time ago...